# suppress viewing indexes - apache

Tags: apache-2.2, indexes

Does this syntax prevent indexes to be visable in var/www?

```
 <Directory "/var/www">
   Options FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride All
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
 </Directory>
```

or do is "Options -Indexes" required in httpd.conf or .htaccess?

Answer (score 2):

Not trying to be mean, but [**Have you read the Apache Manual?**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options)

Relevant text:

> Normally, if multiple Options could apply to a directory, then the
>   most specific one is used and others are ignored; the options are not
>   merged. (See how sections are merged.) However if all the options on
>   the Options directive are preceded by a + or - symbol, the options are
>   merged. Any options preceded by a + are added to the options currently
>   in force, and any options preceded by a - are removed from the options
>   currently in force.

It's a bit dense, but what it's saying is essentially "either will work, as long as there is no `Options` directive later that overrides it". If you want to be *certain*, you should specify `-Indexes` for each directory you want to protect.